# flowplayer html5 play button on controlbar missing

Tags: html, flowplayer

I'm trying to add a simple play button to the flowplayer controlbar, but it seems that it's not possible. I tried it with the `play-button` styling parameter, but no use.
Searching google didn't get me any clues either.\
What else could I try to get and style a play button on the controlbar?

Comment: Do you have any link online where this issue is visible?

Comment: http://flowplayer.blacktrash.org/graceful.html - When flash is turned off in browser, play button dissapears.

Comment: What browser are you using? I turned off flash in Firefox and the play button seems to be perfectly visible.

Comment: I used Firefox, the small play button dissapears after I turn off flash.

Comment: what version of Firefox are you using? Place a screenshot link for the same.

Comment: For some reason it now works for all browsers, I think I changed some css on the player div.